# Checking the correct use of IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, exception, illegalstateexception

Following is the code of CompleteGraph, which basically takes in a list of nodes, then takes in adjacencies/edges of all the nodes. There a function called `getAdj` which throws IllegalState, simply because, according to logic, graph is still under construction, and use has invoked this function even before the user had completely constructed.  Was this a correct decision to use IllegalState ?

```
public class CompleteGraph<T> {

    private final Map<T, HashMap<T, Double>> graph;
    private Set<T> nodes;

    public CompleteGraph() {
        graph = new HashMap<T, HashMap<T, Double>>();
    } 

    public void addNodes (Set<T> nodes) {
        if (nodes == null) throw new NullPointerException("The node cannot be null.");
        if (nodes.size() == 0) throw new NullPointerException("The size of node cannot be zero.");
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public void addEdges (T nodeId, Map<T, Double> addEdges) {
        if (!nodes.contains(nodeId)) throw new NoSuchElementException("The source node: " + nodeId +  " does not exist.");

        for (T node : addEdges.keySet()) {
            if (!nodes.contains(node)) throw new NoSuchElementException("The target node: " + nodeId + "  not exist.");
        }

        graph.put(nodeId, (HashMap<T, Double>) addEdges);
    }

    public Map<T, Double> getAdj (T nodeId) {
        if (!nodes.contains(nodeId)) throw new NoSuchElementException("The node " + nodeId + " does not exist.");
        if (!graph.containsKey(nodeId)) throw new IllegalStateException("The graph is not populated with " + nodeId); 

        return graph.get(nodeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: The main design problem is not with the use of exceptions. The main design problem is that you have a method addNodes() which replaces the nodes instead of adding them, and that you force the caller to use two different methods, in the right order, to populate the graph, leaving it in an inconsistent state after the constructor call, and after the first method call. Your constructor should leave the graph in a correct state, and each method call should migrate the graph state to another, consistent state.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]